# Java - Can't access specific windows registry folder/values

Tags: java, windows, registry

I'm currently trying to get the windows 10 Accent Color value from the registry.

I'm using the WinRegistry example found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java), and can access most of the registry.

Unfortunately I'm getting null when trying to get values at : 
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\DWM`

I can read `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows` without issue, but the DWM folder seems to be protected in some ways.

Code :

```
List<String> toto = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> tata = new ArrayList<String>();

toto = WinRegistry.readStringSubKeys(WinRegistry.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows");
tata = WinRegistry.readStringSubKeys(WinRegistry.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\DWM");
```

Console :

```
 Windows folder content : [CurrentVersion, DWM, Shell, TabletPC, Windows Error Reporting, Winlogon]
DWM Content : []
```

Did anyone successfully get the values contained in DWM?